# Building nativescript plugin strips out typings

Tags: nativescript, typescript-typings, nativescript-plugin

A have written a nativescript plugin using the [official plugin seed from github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed)

It's a very simple plugin and has only 2 source files:

1. index.ts
2. index.d.ts

(and a native library)

In `index.ts`, I re-export some native classes like this:

```js
export const BlufiClient = com.esp32.blufi.BlufiClient;
export const BlufiCallback = com.esp32.blufi.BlufiCallback;
```

and I have my typings for said classes in `index.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '@freevse/nativescript-blufi'{
  export class BlufiClient{
        ctor, functions, etc...
  }

  export abstract class BlufiCallback {
        ctor, functions, etc...
  }
}
```

My issue is that when using the `pack.sh` script in the 'publish' folder, both of the class typings above become (the resulting index.d.ts file contains):

```js
export declare const BlufiClient: any;
export declare const BlufiCallback: any;
```

All the typings I wrote are squashed by `any`...

The repo is available [here](https://github.com/FREEVSE/nativescript-blufi)

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
}
```

was the issue. tsc was overwriting my handwritten typings with generated ones.